# getSystemService error inside Thread class

Tags: android, multithreading, notifications, system

```
public class myThread extends Thread
{
Context context;

public myThread (Context c)
{
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    super.run();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
}
```

I am getting an red x error in eclipse on getSystemService saying `The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type myThread'

HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is defined in the `Context` class, you can't access it from your current class which extends `Thread`.

You have to use your `context` variable and do this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```